# How to Know The Initial Data type is UTF-8 or UTF-16 in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

In [this](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html), the function `sqlite3_column_type` can tell me whether the initial data type of the result is text or not, but it will not tell whether it is **UTF-8** or **UTF-16**. Is there a way to know that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a brand new empty database, before any tables are created, you can set the internal encoding used for Unicode text with the [encoding](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding) pragma, and later use it to see the encoding being used (It defaults to UTF-8).

When storing or retrieving TEXT values, sqlite will automatically convert if needed between UTF-8 and UTF-16, so it doesn't matter too much which one is being used internally unless you're trying to get every last tiny bit of performance out of it.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided it says explicitely:

> const unsigned char *sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);
>   const void *sqlite3_column_text16(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);
>
> sqlite3_column_text   →   UTF-8 TEXT result 
> sqlite3_column_text16 →  UTF-16
>   TEXT result
>
> These routines return information about a single column of the current
>   result row of a query. In every case the first argument is a pointer
>   to the prepared statement that is being evaluated (the sqlite3_stmt*
>   that was returned from sqlite3_prepare_v2() or one of its variants)
>   and the second argument is the index of the column for which
>   information should be returned. The leftmost column of the result set
>   has the index 0. The number of columns in the result can be determined
>   using sqlite3_column_count().